# Get all the modified lines within a file programatically in Visal Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to figure out a way to retrieve all the modified/added lines in a file on Visual Studio. Is there anything on the VS SDK that allow you to do that?

Comment: To clarify, you mean the same as the yellow/green bars you get on the left side for changed/saved lines?

Comment: Correct! I need that for a later function to run some static analysis on these lines only.

Comment: @user3587624 I'm not sure that really makes sense.  Those "changed lines" indications are only the lines that have been changed since that file was actually opened.  If you close and re-open the tab, those changes disappear.

Comment: Are you saying then that there is no real way to figure out what lines were changed since the file was opened?